# Gherkin feature Cannot match any method with step

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, bdd, xunit, gherkin

I'm a BDD test

```
Feature: Register
    I want to register for Authenticator
    Using my name and email 

Scenario: Register for Authenticator
    Given I enter "Joe" "I" and "Doe" name, "joe.doe@ngc.com", "Password123$$$" and true to Terms of Use
    When I press register button
    Then I redirected to confirmation page
```

and I have unit test in xunit:

```
[Given(@"I enter ""(\w+)"" ""(\w+)"" and ""(\w+)"" name, ""(\w+)"", ""(\w+)"" and (.*) to Terms of Use")]
        public void I_enter_registration_information(string first, string middle, string last, string email, string password, bool agree)
        {
        }
```

When I run my test, I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Cannot match any method with step
>   `Given I enter "Joe" "I" and "Doe" name, "joe.doe@ngc.com",
>   "Password123$$$" and true to Terms of Use`. Scenario `Register for
>   Authenticator`

I have tried different regex combination from this [documentation](https://github.com/ttutisani/Xunit.Gherkin.Quick/blob/master/docs/step-attributes.md)

I'm using this library: Xunit.Gherkin.Quick

what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my POV, your code and plain text are both just fine.

However, it looks as if it might have turned one of your arguments into a list, rather than parsing the full string. I suspect it's something to do with the commas. (A quick check is to see if it works without the commas.)

Try using a non-greedy capture:

```
""(\w+?)""
```

I can't find any documentation suggesting that Gherkin should parse commas in that way, so it might be a bug with the library.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the `Xunit.Gherkin.Quick`.

Your regex does not match the input.

Input: `I enter "Joe" "I" and "Doe" name, "joe.doe@ngc.com", "Password123$$$" and true to Terms of Use`

Regex: `I enter "(\w+)" "(\w+)" and "(\w+)" name, "(\w+)", "(\w+)" and (.*) to Terms of Use` (I replaced double quotes with single quotes, because you had double quotes due to escaped string operator `@` in front of the regex).

It cannot match an email address `joe.doe@ngc.com` with regex `(\w+)`. Same problem with matching `Password123$$$` with regex `(\w+)`. You need to use a correct regex that matches the whole input.

e.g., you can fix your regex like this to match: `I enter "(\w+)" "(\w+)" and "(\w+)" name, "(.+)", "(.+)" and (.*) to Terms of Use`. Now, replace single quotes with double quotes if you are going to put it into your attribute and that's it:

```
    [Given(@"I enter ""(\w+)"" ""(\w+)"" and ""(\w+)"" name, ""(.+)"", ""(.+)"" and (.*) to Terms of Use")]
    public void I_enter_registration_information(string first, string middle, string last, string email, string password, bool agree)
    {
    }
```

I tested and it works fine after this fix. The only trick was to follow the regex rules.

Comment: @capiono Tengiz is right; of course \w doesn't match non-alpha! If you can mark this the right answer instead of mine, please do. My answer is misleading. I can't delete it until it's been unaccepted.